# Implement plugin specific settings in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for Redmine and encountered an issue of how to implement plugin specific settings in Redmine in the most neat way.

Is it possible to have a plugin specific settings in `{redmine_home}/plugin/{my_plugin}/config/settings.yml` while sharing with a core a model (in MVC terms) logic which reads YAML file, sets attributes of the model class, provides easy access to them, etc. (`{redmine_home}/app/models/setting.rb`)

I think copypasting or `require`'ing the core model in the plugin model is definitely a poor design so right now i'm tending to have a plugin specific settings in the core config `{redmine_home}/config/settings.yml` and when it comes to plugin controller to read a settings it relies on the core model to do that. (`{redmine_home}/app/models/setting.rb`)

Is this a proper design? Is there any better ways to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked 3 different plugins in our project all used something like:

```
options = YAML::load( File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'plugins/fancy_plugin/config', 'settings.yml')))
```

So just copy pasting.